# Getting error while installing library from pod

Tags: xcode, terminal, cocoapods, dependency-management

I am getting undefined method `squish' for #<String:0x00007fd3a494cd00> (NoMethodError) while installing pod using` **pod install**`. Attaching screenshot for this. Please help me.

[image: Click to see image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something wrong in `activesupport-6.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb`

do the following
`gem uninstall activesupport -v 6.0.0.rc2`
and then
`gem install rails -v 6.1`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try uninstall cocoapods and install latest version of cocoapods ?

```
$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

After that run:

```
pod update
```

I hope, this will solve your problem

Comment: You can see from the log that it is already using 1.10.0, the latest version

Comment: @VedRauniyar you sure import your pod files correctly?

Comment: My guess is a problem with the ruby environment

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem, and I fix this problem by changing the pod version to 1.9.3 in Gemfile.