# undefined method `squish' for #<String:0x00007fe20c941600> (NoMethodError) Error

Tags: ruby

I run the command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Then I get the following error：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
12: from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
11: from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
10: from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
 9: from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/pod:23:in `load'
 8: from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
 7: from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
 6: from /Users/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
 5: from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
 4: from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
 3: from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:205:in `podfile'
 2: from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:226:in `podfile_path'
 1: from /Users/***/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.0/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:166:in `installation_root'
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode.rb:123:in `normalize': undefined method `squish' for #<String:0x00007fbdf0a44290> (NoMethodError)
```

what should I  do

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal

then run the below command -

```
gem uninstall activesupport -v 6.0.0.rc2
```

After that run:

```
gem install rails -v 6.1
```

I hope, this will solve your problem.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Your answer looks exactly like this earlier answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718780/getting-error-while-installing-library-from-pod